# TFS Build Activities associated code

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

[LabDefaultTemplate-> ExecuteRemoteTestRun2 doesn't take in account the Order field of the test in the MTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970203/labdefaulttemplate-executeremotetestrun2-doesnt-take-in-account-the-order-fie)

Referring to this post, what is the way to view the associated Execute method for any CodeActivity. As I could see the ExecuteRemoteTestRun2 is a built in activity and how did the author get to see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tool like Reflector or DotPeek to decompile any .net assembly.